# The uiviewcontroller child of a uiviewcontroller not reacting to touches

Tags: ios, uitableview, first-responder, childviewcontroller

I have a UIViewcontroller that have several views and one uiviewcontroller as childs. The uiviewcontroller include a tableview.
The child uiviewcontroller has the delegate and datasource methods.

I can see the tableview, the delegate build right the table, but I cant scroll or select the cells because the child uiviewcontroller don't react to touches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the child uiviewcontroller to be a uiview instead of uiviewcontroller.

Comment: but this is not the solution to the issue.